# xpath syntax in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

team = hxs.select ('//table[@class="tablehead"/tbody/tr[contains[.@class, "player"]')

The structure of the web site I whose table I want to select is as follows:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>...</td>
     <td>...</td>
       ...
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Since there are multiple tables in the web site, I only want to select the one whose class is defined as "tablehead". Also, for that table, I only want to select the  tags whose class attributes contain the string "player". My attempt above looks a bit spotty to begin with. I tried running the crawler, and it says that the line I produced above is an invalid xpath line. Any advice would be nice.

Comment: theres a closing bracket missing and as far is I know, contains is a function => contains(@class, "player")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //table[@class="tablehead"/tbody/tr[contains[.@class, "player"]

**Correcting this results in**:

```
//table[@class='tablehead']/tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'player')]
```

This selects every `tr` the string value of whose `class` attribute contains the string `"player"` and that (the `tr`) is a child of a `tbody` that is a child of any `table` in the XML document, whose `class` attribute has string value `"tablehead"` .

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "//table[@class='tablehead']
        /tbody/tr[contains(@class, 'player')]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (made just a little bit more realistic):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="tablehead">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="major-player">
                    <td>player1</td>
                    <td>player2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**the Xpath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (just one in this case) are copied to the output**:

```
<tr class="major-player">
   <td>player1</td>
   <td>player2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It says it's invalid syntax when I try that. The thing is, for hxs.select(), the argument has to be surrounded by single quotes I think. So if "tablehead" and "player" are surrounded instead by single quotes, it might think that the opening single quote of 'tablehead' is closing the outermost single quote.

Comment: @AndrewChen: I have provided verification that the XPath expression is syntactically and semantically correct -- it selects the wanted element. If you still have problems trying to evaluate this expression with SCRAPY, this means that SCRAPY is not a compliant XPath implementation, and you shouldn't tag the question as "xpath".

Comment: @AndrewChen: Of course it isn't working -- can't you see that this is syntacrically illegal? Use the corrected XPath expression from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've came across these problems before, try to omit `tbody` in the xpath expression.

Comment: I think its a bug in Scrapy it doesnt process `tbody` at all ... weird .. sucks